# Regex - Unicode combining character sequence \x - text terminal

Tags: regex

In this [pdf document](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/16104-102-2-62551/regex.pdf) in **VI. Other Special Characters** says

> e. ANSCII or ANSI codes
>   1. Codes that control appearance of a text terminal
>   2. 0xA9 = \xA9

I can't understand "appearance of a text terminal".
What does it mean?

Comment: Try `echo -e '\033[31mRED\033[m'` in your terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the author meant terminal attributes like text and background color, character set, character attributes (bold, underscored, blinking, inverse) etc.